# How do I validate this string that can be enclosed between one or more spaces (but never none) via a regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, if-statement

This is my code:

```py
input_text_l = "hjahsdjhas pal sahashjas"

regex= re.compile(r"\s*\¿?(?:pal1|pal2|pal)\s*\??") #THIS IS THE REGEX THAT DOES NOT WORK CORRECTLY

if regex.search(input_text_l):

    not_tag = " ".join(regex_tag.split(input_text_l))
    #print(not_tag)

else:
    pass
```

And this is a simple diagram on how the regular expression should work.

[image]

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Do you mean you want just `re.split(r'\s*\b(?:pal1|pal2|pal)\b\s*', input_text_l)`? If it is actual regex and not some simplified version, you could even write it as `r'\s*\bpal[12]?\b\s*'`. To match one or more whitespaces, use `\s+` instead of `\s*` and then you would not need word boundaries `\b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do complicated things: `\s+…\s+` is sufficient. `+` is actually exactly what you wrote: "*one or more but not none*"

```
import re
re.search('\s+pal\s+', input_text_l)
```

or for several patterns:

```
re.search('\s+(?:pal1|pal2|pal)\s+', input_text_l)
```

Example:

```
>>> input_text_l = "hjahsdjhas pal sahashjas"
>>> re.search('\s+(?:pal1|pal2|pal)\s+', input_text_l)
<re.Match object; span=(10, 15), match=' pal '>
```

Comment: FWIW the regex could be simplified to `\spal[12]?\s` or, if you actually want to permit a match at beginning or end of line too, `\bpal[12]\b`

Comment: @triplee yes of course but I assumed (maybe incorrectly) that those were dummy names ;)

Comment: @tripleee I did not know that you could do that, to consider similar cases, such as pal1, pal2, pal3, pal4, pal5, ..., paln, in that case it would be pal [12345]?

Comment: @ElectrisikVocal yes, without the space `pal[12345]` or even `pal[1-5]`

Comment: @mozway Yes your code is correct and works for me, I put pal2, pal1 or pal as dummy names, just to test the code.

Comment: Notice that `[...]` is a character class, which matches a single character out of the enumeration; if you need to list alternatives of arbitrary length, that's still `(alternative|option|choice|offer)` (with `(?:` at the beginning if you don't need or want grouping).